# Reference Request: Proof of $\mathrm{H}(\mathrm{Prim}\,\mathcal{H}) \cong \mathrm{Prim}\,\mathrm{H}(\mathcal{H})$ for cocommutative dg-Hopf algebras

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

In Loday’s book *Cyclic Homology* the following theorem appears:

> **A.9 Theorem.**
>   On a cocommutative differential graded Hopf algebra $\mathcal{H}$ over a characteristic zero field $k$ the homology and primitive functors commute,
>   $$
>   \operatorname{H}(\operatorname{Prim} \mathcal{H})
>   \cong
>   \operatorname{Prim} \operatorname{H}(\mathcal{H}) \,.
> $$

For a proof of this theorem Loday refers to Appendix B of Quillen’s *Rational Homotopy Theory*, but it seems to me that the assertion does not appear there.

> **Question**:
>   Where can a proof of the above theorem can be found?